# Sending email using SMTP

Tags: java, smtp

hi I have written this code to connect SMTP it is working fine for smtp.gmail.com but not for my client for IP 10.5.128.146 with port no 25.

here the code is ..... can you suggest me any solution.

```
 import java.util.Properties;
 import javax.mail.Message;
 import javax.mail.MessagingException;
 import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
 import javax.mail.Session;
 import javax.mail.Transport;
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailSSL {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "10.5.128.146");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");
            }
        });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@mydomain.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("abc@otherdomain.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

it shows connection time out error.
anyone can tell me is this really a programming problem or server side problem.if server side then what can I suggest them to do.

Thnaks in Adance

Comment: Isn't smtps usually port 465 (and not 25)?

Comment: is there any output in the smtp log? I've had a lot of trouble in the past and it mostly comes down to (in the case of corporate networks) that my servers ip address is not allowed to send emails, there is a firewall block or something of that sort. Check the smtp log and see if anything of use is in there. If there is no record of even a connection, see if you can ping the smtp server from your server.

Comment: I have ping from my server to there but reply comes request timed out

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have modified a GMail connection snippet.  GMail requires SSL but a traditional "port 25" SMTP server does not so the handshake does not work properly.

I would suggest removing the mail.smtp.socketFactory.class and mail.smtp.auth properties.

Comment: if I remove smtp.auth.properties, then would I be able to chk the username and passwd?

Comment: If you remove the property `mail.smtp.socketFactory.class`, it will use the default (non-SSL) SocketFactory and when you connect to port 25, it should be fine. If you want to do SSL, you need to use an SSL SMTP port (like 465)

Answer (score 1):

Timed out suggests that port 25 is firewalled and the firewall is simply dropping packets, rather than replying with a connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

check to see if you are able to telnet on port 25 for that IP of yours...if you are able to telnet, that means the port is not firewalled and there are connectivity issues....if it is blocked by the firewall, you need to apply rules to allow this connection!!!