# Send mail in java servlet works but from address and subject is unknown

Tags: java, servlets

This is a little mailing script that gets the information from the form and then sends a mail.
It works like a charm only one problem is that the from address and the subject isn't working. The mail comes without a from address and without a subject.

Someone that knows what's wrong?

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    //SMTPserver en de mail naar waar de mensen hun mail versturen
    String smtpServ = "uit.telenet.be";
    String to = "ddd@gmail.com";


    String from = request.getParameter("mail");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject") + "geschreven door: " + request.getParameter("naam");
    String emailContent = request.getParameter("beschrijving");

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    try {

      sendMessage(smtpServ, to, from, subject, emailContent);

    } catch (Exception e) {

      throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());

    }
}       


private void sendMessage(String smtpServer, String to, String from,
    String subject, String emailContent) throws Exception {
 try{
     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
     client.from(from);
     client.to(to);
     PrintStream message = client.startMessage();
     message.println("Naar: " + to);
     message.println("Onderwerp:" + subject);
     message.println(emailContent);
     message.println();
     message.println("Het Burgerdemocratie Team");
     message.println();     
     message.println();
     client.closeServer();
  }
  catch (IOException e){    
     System.out.println("ERROR tijdens het verzenden van de mail:"+e);
  }
```

}

Comment: What is there in SmtpClient? Post its code here or a link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add to **sendMessage()** method this:

```
message.println("To: " + to);  
message.println("Subject: " + subject);
```

Comment: Thanks, the subject works but my sender is always unknown and i'm testing it with a gmail or whatever mail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use sun classes (according to the name SmtpClient, we don't have the import lines).

You should use **javax.mail** classes.

All the features you are trying to get are available : setSubject, setFrom, etc ...

Here is an example :
[Sending email using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263053/sending-email-using-smtp)

Comment: the only problem is, i'm working in springe source suite, and the imports of that topic doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to add mail.jar and activation.jar (they come from Sun). The homepage at oracle : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html